# Return a dict in a function, then print its contents in another function

Tags: python

I have a function (items) that returns a dict (details_dict) and would like to print out this dict in another function (contents).

The contents of details_dict after the for loop are to be:

```
details_dict = {
'car' : 'fast',
'bike' : 'faster',
'train' : 'slow'
 }
```

Here are the two functions i implemented but i am not sure if they are right.

```
def items(root):
  for a in list:   # example for loop, not important but details_dict is created here 
       details_dict = ['name' : 'state']
  return details_dict

def contents(root):
  for name, state in details_dict.items():
         print ("%s is set to %s" % (name, state)
```

Comment: Is details_dict already created? If so, why is it being recreated (albeit wrong) in the items function? What is the items function doing?

Comment: No it is not, it is created in items(root) via a for loop, il edit the question

Comment: *i am not sure if they are right.* - [try it and see](https://repl.it/CeJY/0). Does it work? What does it do instead of working?

Comment: The indentation inside your `for` loops is incorrect, but that might be an aberration of pasting code - please check.

Comment: @cdarke fixed, but I'm more concerned regarding the syntax within the contents function is correct?

Comment: You have the `return` statement inside the `for` loop, so the function ends after the first iteration. What is `list`? And why doesn't the function use the `root` argument?

Comment: It is better to be sure that it is wrong and know how it is wrong (what it does instead) then to be unsure, come back when you can tell us exactly what went wrong when being run.

Comment: The final `print` statement is missing a `)`.  In `contents` you are passing `root` but iterating through `details_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing parenthesis in your print statement and possible indentation issues. Here's a modified version of what you're doing, ignoring the details of how the dict is built:

```
def buildItems():
    return {
        'car': 'fast',
        'bike': 'faster',
        'train': 'slow'
    }

def contents():
    details_dict = buildItems()
    for name, state in details_dict.items():
        print ("%s is set to %s" % (name, state))

contents()
```

Outputs:

```
car is set to fast
train is set to slow
bike is set to faster
```

If that's what you want it to do, it works. You can successfully print the dict created in another function from inside the contents() function.

Comment: Notice that in Python, dict's do not preserve order. If you need to preserve order, try an [OrderedDict] (https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your data I have made a best guess.

```
list_a = ['car', 'bike', 'train']
list_b = ['fast', 'faster', 'slow']

def items (one, two):
    the_dict = {}
    for (i,j) in zip(one, two):
        the_dict[i] = j
    return the_dict

def contents(a_dict):
    for key in a_dict:
        print 'The key ' +key+ ' is assigned to '+a_dict[key]

details_dict = items(list_a, list_b)

contents(details_dict)
```

which outputs:

```
The key car is assigned to fast
The key train is assigned to slow
The key bike is assigned to faster
```